# NSPredicate with to-many to-many relationships

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am having some trouble writing a predicate for my NSFetchedResultsController to get all `Modifier` from a table where where `Exercise` and `Modifier` contain the same `Exercise_Modifier`

The model look like this: `Exercise` <->>>`Exercise_Modifier`<<<->`Modifier`

I've tried using `ANY` and `ALL` keywords but cannot seem to get to the answer. I've tried this along the line of this:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ALL exercise_modifiers == %@", exercise!.modifiers!)
```

where `exercise_modifiers` is the relationship from `Modifier` <->>>`Exercise_Modifier` and `exercise!.modifiers!` are the `Exercise_Modifier` for the current exercise I have. Does anyone know where I might be missing something?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that Exercise_Modifier is there only so that you can have a many-to-many relationship between Exercise and Modifier? This is not needed in Core Data because you can set up that relationship directly between Exercise and Modifier.

Comment: Sort of, in the DB each exercise contains a list of modifier names it has, then another table contains that modifier name with it's other info nested inside. The linking table is way to save an exercise's valid modifiers when the DB is called to

Comment: Sounds to me like you can have a many-to-many relationship between them then. Remember you're designing and working with an object model and the database is only there to persist your objects.